# How to install lispbuilder-sdl with SBCL?

Tags: windows, installation, lisp, sdl, sbcl

So I was reading through some documentations from the lispbuilder-sdl website and it seemed very confusing at parts where it says "install to: ..." 
Can anyone give me some detailed instructions on how to install lispbuilder-sdl with SBCL on a windows pc?

Documentation:
https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/WindowsSBCL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Introduction

OK, since this [LispBuilder](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/) may be really interesting thing, let's give it a try.

Here, I use Windows 7 and SBCL 1.2.1. Assuming that SBCL has been successfully installed on your system, let's skip the step [Install SBCL](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/WindowsSBCL#Install__SBCL).

## [Installing CFFI and Dependencies](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/WindowsSBCL#Install_CFFI_and_Dependencies)

We need to install CFFI and its dependencies. [Here is tarballs](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/releases/?M=D). We need [cffi_latest.tar.gz](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/releases/cffi_latest.tar.gz).

Next, we will need [Babel](http://common-lisp.net/project/babel/). But what's up with it? Official download page shows '404 Not Found'. Oh, no. Get it as zip archive from [GitHub](https://github.com/cl-babel/babel).

Get [Alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/). Since other links are really obsolete, get [it form GitHub](https://github.com/keithj/alexandria) as zip archive.

We also need [Trivial Features](http://www.cliki.net/trivial-features). Again from GitHub. Since authors of this library create releases, I prefer download it from [release page](https://github.com/trivial-features/trivial-features/releases).

OK, now untar and unzip these four libararies. So, for example, I have the following directories:

> alexandria-master
>   babel-master
>   cffi_0.13.0
>   trivial-features-0.7

Next, we have to move all that stuff into 'site' direcotry of SBCL. What is it and where is it located on Windows? I think 'site' is something like 'site-lisp' for Emacs. [SBCL documentation](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Extensions) isn't so kind to give a word of explanation about this directory. Perhaps, it has nothing to do with SBCL at all. Well, let's just create it inside of installation directory of SBCL, for example:

> C:\Program Files\Steel Bank Common Lisp\1.2.1\site\

Then, let's put all our stuff into this directory and rename subdirectories as showed in the manual:

> alexandria-master -> alexandria
>   babel-master -> babel
>   cffi_0.13.0 -> cffi
>   trivial-features-0.7 -> trivial-features

## [Install LISPBUILDER-SDL and Binaries](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/WindowsSBCL#Install_LISPBUILDER-SDL_and_Binaries)

OK, let's download LispBuilder from [here](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/downloads/list). Lotsa stuff here, I guess we need [this](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/downloads/detail?name=lispbuilder-sdl-0.9.8.1.tgz&can=2&q=), and also [this](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/downloads/detail?name=win32-lispbuilder-sdl-binaries-1.2.14.tgz&can=2&q=).

Untar these archives into 'site' directory:

> C:\Program Files\Steel Bank Common Lisp\1.2.1\site\lispbuilder-sdl\

## [Create an SBCL System Initialization File](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/WindowsSBCL#Create_an_SBCL_System_Initialization_File)

Create file 'sbclrc' in your SBCL installation directory with the following contents:

```
(require :asdf)

;; put all subdirectories of [SBCL]\site\ into asdf:*central-registry*
(dolist (dir (directory "[SBCL]\\site\\*\\"))
  (pushnew dir asdf:*central-registry* :test #'equal))

;; load lispbuilder-sdl
(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :lispbuilder-sdl)
(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :lispbuilder-sdl-binaries)
```

## [Try the Examples](https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/WindowsSBCL#Try_the_Examples)

This is my favorite part. Start SBCL and it should compile lots of stuff. Wait for a second. When you see something like:

```
;
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 502 STYLE-WARNING conditions
;   printed 13 notes
*
```

It's time for fun:

```
* (asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :lispbuilder-sdl-examples)
```

This command will compile and load examples. Manual suggests this for trying:

```
* (sdl-examples:mandelbrot)
```

Works. Looks like some fractal graphic.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org):

```
(ql:system-apropos "lispbuilder")
```

shows the available (sub-)systems.  Install with `ql:quickload`.